# How to add date to docx document using reporteRs in R?

Tags: r, reporters

I can only find information about adding a date (ideally the current date based on when the report is run) to pptx document in reporteRs. Is there a way to add the current date to a docx document?

Thank you!

Comment: Interesting. Where did you look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library( ReporteRs )
mydoc = docx( )
mydoc = addParagraph( mydoc, value = as.character(Sys.time()), stylename = "Normal" )
mydoc = addParagraph( mydoc, value = as.character(Sys.Date()), stylename = "Normal" )
writeDoc( mydoc, file = tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".docx"))
shell.exec(tf)
```

[image]

pptx works [just like that](https://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/powerpoint.html)...